# (AS3) Small currentFrame Issue

Tags: actionscript-3

Okay, for some reason, this is returning 1 and only 1:

```
for each(var i in bManager.bulletVector){
    trace(i.currentFrame);
}

if (i.parent != null && i.currentFrame > 1) { 
    trace("TRACED"); //Never executes
    i.parent.removeChild(i);
    bManager.bulletVector.splice(bManager.bulletVector.indexOf(i), 1);
}
```

The instances play normally, but for some reason, Flash thinks that they're still on frame 1. I might've forgotten something, but I'm really stuck. All help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't loop through children like this in AS3. Look at numChildren and getChildAt()

Comment: Wow, this goes against everything that I've learned. I'll test it out to see if it works once I get home.

Comment: You must have learned in AS2 ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing question, yada yada yada. Also, using `currentFrame` is a bad idea.